# Google speech API JSON parsing in python?

Tags: python, json

I have gotten the response of google json api and saved the file in a json file which looks like this

JSON file [drive.google.com/open?id=1Esuv9KpikqhwccL-dGm-IFfI5S6V7plV](http://why%20this%20code%20isnt%20working%20with%20this%20file%20drive.google.com/open?id=1Esuv9KpikqhwccL-dGm-IFfI5S6V7plV)

And I want to parse it in python 2. I've tried

```
for result in response.results:
        # The first alternative is the most likely one for this portion.
        print('Transcript: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))
        print('Confidence: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].confidence))
```

but it throws the error

```
'str' object has no attribute 'results'
```

later I tried

```
jsondata = json.load(json_file_path)
```

but it says

```
'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = "your json data" # of type `str`
json_dict = json.loads(data)

for result in json_dict["response"]["results"]:
  if "alternatives" in result:
    alternatives = result["alternatives"][0]
    if "confidence" in alternatives:
      print(alternatives["confidence"])
    if "transcript" in alternatives:
      print(alternatives["transcript"])
```

- Use `json.loads` to convert / parse `str` to `dict`
- `"alternatives"` is of type `list`

If your data is coming from a json file, read it first

```
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    # refer to above code
```

Comment: why this code isnt working with this file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Esuv9KpikqhwccL-dGm-IFfI5S6V7plV

Comment: can't access it,

Comment: try now , I have provided access

Comment: Finally it solved the problem , Thanks for the help:)