# Google speech API json parsing?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have obtained the results from google speech in a variable

```
data = {'name': '1235433175192040985', 'metadata': {'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.speech.v1.LongRunningRecognizeMetadata', 'progressPercent': 100, 'startTime': '2018-04-11T12:56:58.237060Z', 'lastUpdateTime': '2018-04-11T12:57:44.944653Z'}, 'done': true, 'response': {'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.speech.v1.LongRunningRecognizeResponse', 'results': [{'alternatives': [{'transcript': 'hi how are you', 'confidence': 0.92438406}]}, {'alternatives': [{'transcript': 'How are you doing?', 'confidence': 0.9402676}]}]}}

json_dict = json.loads(data)
```

On this it throws error

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

For the rest of parsing I wrote

```
for result in json_dict["response"]["results"]:
  if "alternatives" in result:
    alternatives = result["alternatives"][0]
    if "confidence" in alternatives:
      print(alternatives["confidence"])
    if "transcript" in alternatives:
      print(alternatives["transcript"])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any way or in language that i can parse this data, I have tons of this data and I don't want to regenerate all of this again.

Comment: Could you paste the original JSON? `json.loads` receives a string and you are using a `dict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dict doesn't need any further json methods, you can work with it as is.

```
for result in data["response"]["results"]:
  if "alternatives" in result:
    alternatives = result["alternatives"][0]
    if "confidence" in alternatives:
      print(alternatives["confidence"])
    if "transcript" in alternatives:
      print(alternatives["transcript"])
```

Yields this output:

```
0.92438406
hi how are you
0.9402676
How are you doing?
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON parser in Python expects your blob to use double quotation marks, since that is the [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/).

```
{
  "name": "John Doe"
}
```

You could replace the single quotes with double quotes, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21154138/1878974).

However, I’m pretty sure the problem can be solved elsewhere, since the Google API most likely uses valid JSON in it’s responses. How do you parse the response from Google’s API?

Comment: then why google sends the response in single quote form

Comment: I used the above method for parsing the above data but now google changed its responce and the code is failing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49423548/google-speech-api-json-parsing-in-python

Comment: I was using this for older google speech API responses but it isn't working now

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your snippet is that you're passing a dict to json.loads. json.loads decodes json to dict, so it redundant and wrong.
[read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)